# Trying to remove html from a package I downloaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've downloaded the Trumbowyg WYSIWYG editor: http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/ for my site. The toolbar has a lot of buttons for text align, quoting, etc., which I don't need. So I want to remove it, but I'm not sure how exactly to do it because there isn't an HTML file, because the buttons seem to be generated from JavaScript. So I've gone into the JS file where it lists the buttons like this:

```
btns: [/*
            ['viewHTML'],
            ['undo', 'redo'],*/
            ['formatting'],
            'btnGrp-semantic',
            /*['superscript', 'subscript'],
            ['link'],*/
            ['insertImage'],/*
            'btnGrp-justify',
            'btnGrp-lists',
            ['horizontalRule'],
            ['removeformat'],
            ['fullscreen']*/
        ],
```

As you can see I've only left a couple buttons. However this doesn't actually do anything. All the buttons still appear. I can set some buttons to `display:none`, however this isn't good semantically. And this also doesn't work as each button is nested in its own div, but they all have the same class `.trumbowyg-button-group` and no individual identifier. I've tried to remove the individual `.trumbowyg-button-group`s via javascript by using `.css('display', 'none')`, however this isn't working. Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To customize button pane, you don't need to change Trumbowvg's source code. There is a public [API](http://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/documentation.html#button-pane) to do so. You can define the used buttons when initializing Trumbowvg:

```
$('#demo').trumbowyg({
    btns: [['formatting'], 'btnGrp-semantic', ['insertImage']]
});
```

For your approach, I guess it's because you changed the Trumbowvg's `src` code, but didn't build it into its `dist`?

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware of this...saves alot of time. So I've used that function you pasted to remove buttons, which works fine. However all the remaining buttons float left, and I would like them to be centred. Would you know how I can do this? I tried `.trumbowyg-button-group{margin: 0 auto}`, which centres them, but it causes massive gaps between the buttons that i've removed.

Comment: @Zorgan in order to center buttons, you can use `.trumbowyg-button-pane {justify-content: center}`